# C++ new object every time function is called?

Tags: c++, instance

What I want is a function that makes a new different instance every time i call it (with a different name...)

Just like this:

```
void person::new_person(){
  person *(id+index) = new person(name_temp, age_temp, quote_temp);
}
```

But it doesn't work... I don't know how should i do that... (index is add by one every time i make a new instance).
And i realized every time i make a pointer and just add spaces on it, like that:

```
int*p;
*(p+1) = 5;
```

It compiles, but freezes while running(I supose its getting memmory thats not allowed), so that "person *(id+index)" may not work too.
What do you think?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do.  You can't have dynamically generated variable names.  You can create new objects on every function call but you need a dedicated place to store them, whether in a specific variable or array or vector or some other collection...

Comment: In the short term, you need a container, ideally something like `std::vector`. In the long term, you need a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 8):

Try keeping your `person`s in a standard container:

```
std::vector<person> people;
void person::new_person(std::string name, int age, std::string quote){
      people.push_back(person(name, age, quote));
}
```

Comment: Without globals ? Pretty please ?

Comment: Pedagogical question: Should I have make the args `const std::string&`, which will eventually be the right answer, or pass by value to avoid confusing OP?

Comment: @Robᵩ you are going to copy `name` anyway, so you should make it a value argument and then do `people.emplace_back(std::move(name), age, std::move(quote));`.

Comment: @Zoidberg'--: Which might confuse OP even more, but would also be even more right...

Comment: @kbok - doing that would, I think, make too many confusing assumptions about the OP's program.

Comment: i didnt put it there, but i have like "cout << "type name"; cin >> name". But if i make 3 new people, how do i have access to the values of the third?

Comment: @Robᵩ Keep it simple, absolutely. One new thing at a time.

Comment: "62 C:\Dev-Cpp\MyCompilations\Class Person.cpp `vector' is not a member of `std' "

Answer (score 5):

You mean something like this?

```
#include <string>

person make_person()
{
    static unsigned i = 0;
    return person(std::to_string(i++));
}
```

Comment: Why not just return a `person`? There doesn't seem to be any reason for a (smart) pointer here.

Comment: I don't think the `i` is needed, but the ability to pass in parameters is.

Comment: *What I want is a function that makes a new different instance every time i call it (with a different name...)* -- My solution meets all requirements :P

Comment: i dont want to return a person parameter, i want it to make a new instance with a different name every time i use the function...

Answer (score 3):

> “What I want is a function that makes a new different instance every time i call it (with a different name...) ”

That’s known as a **constructor**, and it's a special kind of member function, with the same name as the class. It doesn’t have a function result type, not even `void`. It can go like this:

```
class Person
{
private:
    string name_;

public:
    Person( string name )
        : name_( name )
    {}
};
```

Then there are a variety of ways to call it, depending on where you want the new instance stored. E.g.,

```
int main()
{
    Person a( "A" );    // Local variable
    Person( "B" );      // A temporary, it's already destroyed... ;-)
    vector< Person > v;
    v.emplace_back( "C" );    // As a new item at the end of vector.
}
```

Plus some, but I guess the three ways above are the most relevant to a complete beginner.

Note that with the vector, every time you `push_back` or `emplace_back` you’re creating a new last item, with a new index. Call the `size` method to find out how many items you currently have in a vector. *Check the documentation* for more information.

By the way, you should really get yourself a textbook.

Comment: Interesting interpretation, but due to `person(name_temp, age_temp, quote_temp)` in the question, I'd assume this is an incorrect interpretation.

Comment: 62 C:\Dev-Cpp\MyCompilations\Class Pessoa.cpp `vector' is not a member of `std'

Comment: @DhiegoMagalhães: you have to add the relevant `#include`s and `using` statements. A textbook helps. But just to get you going, for `string` you need `#include <string>`, for `vector` you need `#include <vector>`, and for both you need to either add `std::` in front of the names, or add `using` statements like `using std::string`.